When is $5^n - 1$ a perfect square?
I need to know if there exists a solution to the equation $5^n-1=x^2$ where x,n are integers.
I know that if such an n exists that is must be odd.
If we assume n is even then we get that the difference between two square numbers is exactly 1. If we look at the difference between consecutive squares we see the following:
$$(y+1)^2-y^2 = y^2+2y+1-y^2$$
$$=2y+1$$
So the only time the difference between two squares is 1 is when $y=0$ or between the squares $0^2$ and $1^2$ so for $n>1$ there are no even solutions to the posed problem.
I managed to limit the possibilities for n further by considering what a perfect square would be congruent to mod certain bases. If we take the expression mod 7 we get:
$$x^2\equiv 0,1,2,4(mod 7)$$
$$ b^n \equiv\begin{cases} 
      1 & n\equiv0(mod6) \newline
2 & n\equiv4(mod6) \newline
3 & n\equiv5(mod6) \newline
4 & n\equiv2(mod6) \newline
5 & n\equiv1(mod6) \newline
6 & n\equiv3(mod6) \newline
   \end{cases}(mod7)
$$
therefore the only time $b^n-1 \equiv x^2(mod7)$ is when $n\equiv0,1,4,5(mod 6)$. However, since we know n must also be even we can conclude a valid n must be congruent to 1 or 5 mod 6.
You can do this with other bases to further restrict the conditions on n, but I have yet to find a way to show that such an n can't exist.
Is it true that there are no non-trivial ($n>1$) solutions to the equation?

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread Number Theory.

If n = 2k then $5^n =(5^k+1)(5^k-1)$

Take mod 2 to eliminate x is an odd integer

By Catalan's conjecture, the only two positive consecutive perfect powers are $8$ and $9$.
If $5^n-1=x^2$ and $x$ is an integer we need $5^n$ to be an integer. This means $n\ge0$ since $n$ is an integer.
If $n=0$ then $x=0$. If $n=1$ then $x^2=4$ so $x=2$ or $x=-2$.
If $n>1$ then $5^n$ is a positive perfect power and $5^n-1=x^2$ is also a positive perfect power so $5^n=9$. But $9$ is not a power of $5$. Contradiction.
Answer: $(n,x)=(0,0),(1,2),(1,-2)$

Let $n$ and $x$ be integers such that
$$5^n-1=x^2.\tag{1}$$
The right hand side is an integer, so the left hand side is also an integer, which implies $n\geq0$. Of course if $(n,x)$ is a solution then so is $(n,-x)$, so we restrict our attention to nonnegative $x$. For small $n$ we find the solutions $(n,x)=(0,0)$ and $(n,x)=(1,2)$. For $n\geq2$ we must have $x\geq3$, and the left hand side of $(1)$ is even, so $x$ is even. Then reducing mod $8$ shows that $n$ is even, say $n=2m$, and so
$$x^2=5^n-1=(5^m+1)(5^m-1),$$
where the greatest common divisor of the two factors on the right hand side is $2$. By unique factorization this implies
$$5^m+1=2y^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 5^m-1=2z^2,$$
for some positive integers $y$ and $z$. It folows that
$$2y^2-2z^2=(5^m+1)-(5^m-1)=2,$$
which in turn implies that $y^2-z^2=1$, which is of course impossible because $y$ and $z$ are both positive. So the only solutions are $(n,x)=(0,0)$ and $(n,x)=(1,\pm2)$.

Why can't $n$ be odd and both sides be $4\bmod 8$?
